# Syntaxes and IN(each) instead of IN(or) issues in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i'm a begginer in databases. My issue is hard to explain with words since i'm not that good in english, so here is what i would do :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(link)
FROM foo
WHERE
(
  foo.name IN('bar1' AND 'bar2')
)
AND
(
  foo.text IN('bar3' AND 'bar4' AND ...)
)
AND
(
  foo.desc = 'bar'
)
AND (...) etc..
LIMIT 100
```

if found this solution seems working great but not in my case of multiple WHERE statements (when syntaxe doesn't allow to have groupby+having in each parentheses):

```
foo.name IN('bar1', 'bar2') // len = 2
GROUP BY link
HAVING COUNT(foo.name) = 2  // len
```

May be difficult to understand so here is an simple example of table :

```
| id | link | name |
| -- | ---- | ---- |
| 01 | HG.C | bar1 |
| 02 | IJ.N | bar2 |
| 03 | HG.C | bar2 |
| 03 | SZ.W | bar3 |

SELECT DISTINCT(link)
FROM foo
WHERE
(
  foo.name IN('bar1' AND 'bar2')
)
```

It should return : HG.C

I tried many things that failed so i'm still looking for a way... i guess my brain isn't formatted (yet) for SQL. If somebody can help me, would be so nice.

Comment: On a sidenote: `DISTINCT` is not a function. So your parentheses are only confusing. You should remove them. (However, you don't want `DISTINCT` here anyway, but an aggregation with `GROUP BY` instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an aggregation, where you get one result row per `link`. But you only want to show links that match certain criteria. Use a HAVING clause to filter the results:

```
SELECT link
FROM foo
GROUP BY link
HAVING SUM(name = 'bar1') > 0
   AND SUM(name = 'bar2') > 0
   AND SUM(text = 'bar3') > 0
   AND SUM(text = 'bar4') > 0
   AND SUM(desc = 'bar') > 0;
```

This only shows you links that have records with name = 'bar1' and also records with name = 'bar2' and also ...

The query makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0. So with `SUM(name = 'bar1')` we count occurrences.

If needed you can ask for combined criteria, too:

```
AND SUM(name = 'bar2' AND text = 'bar4') > 0
```

You can add a WHERE clause to speed this up (so as to only look at records that have a name 'bar1' or 'bar2' and a text 'bar3' or 'bar4' etc.).

Comment: Thank you soooo much, this is saving my day.
I hope this will not be too long because i do this on a really big database, but i'll try with the WHERE clause as you suggest.